# Jython AttributeError: read-only attr

Tags: java, jython, readonly

I am trying to write a program about a .py extend a java interface, just like an [example on IBM developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/java/j-lo-jythonconfig/).

But I got a problem like:

```
AttributeError: read-only attr: cardID
```

But the strange thing is if I rename the cardID to cardNum，it works. Here my code:

CardInfo.py

```
from com.jyt import CardInfo
class CardInfo(CardInfo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cardName = "Dark Magician"
        self.cardID = "888"

    def getName(self):
        return self.cardName

    def getCardID(self):
        return self.cardID

    def setID(self,newID):
        self.cardID = newID
```

and the java interface:

```
public interface CardInfo {
    public String getCardID();
    public String getName();
    public void setID();
}
```

and the java file

```
        Object javaObject;
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
//      PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
        interpreter.execfile("./res/CardInfo.py");
        interpreter.exec("cardInfo=CardInfo()");
        PyObject pyObject = interpreter.get("cardInfo");
        pyObject.invoke("setID",new PyString("12345"));
        try{
            javaObject = pyObject.__tojava__(CardInfo.class);
            CardInfo cardInfo = (CardInfo)javaObject;
            System.out.println(cardInfo.getCardID());
            System.out.println(cardInfo.getName());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: seems that cardID is a KeyWord or Something,I have tried CardNID，CID，etc，it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess (can't test it right now because I'm not on my own pc), but your problem is probably related to the (somewhat underdocumented) fact that [jython generates property accessors for javas getter/setter methods](http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#javabean-properties), which clash with your attribute names and thus shadow your actual attribute.

If my hypothesis is correct, the problem in this case is that you have a getter method which has the same name (minus the `get` part) as the attribute. Jython sees the method and generates a property for it, which is `read-only` because there is no matching setter method.

It may be that you could fix this by just renaming your `setID` method to `setCardID` so jython correctly interprets the attribute as writable. If this doesn't work for some reason, one of the following should definitely work:

- rename the attribute to something else, like `self.myCardID`
- alternatively, rename the method to something else, like `getID`

Both of these solutions should cause the attribute to no longer be shadowed by the property accessor.

Comment: It can be solved by rename the attribute but not the method,I've debug with the jython source code,it happends in init function "self.cardID"，so you're right,but otherwise,I can't find anything about "cardID" in the code.Anyway,it's just strange to me,it can be solved very easy.Now I've aready made up the jython factory,but it's slow on running the script.